# Why is my physics code emitting almost everywhere as occupied?

Tags: java, physics, rgb, bufferedimage

I am making a falling-sand like game with the usual physics rules for these games.

It works on the fact that I load my levels from a file.

So, to check whether a place is empty, it checks the `RGB` value on the loaded level.

But for some reason, it returns that almost every cell (apart from the same few cells) is occupied by something, even when it is not.

The physics is handled by loading a file initially, then modifying it.

The file type is PNG format, and the `BufferedImage` type is `TYPE_INT_ARGB`

Here is all the physics handling code in the main class.

```
public static void updateParticles()
    {
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
        for(int j=0;j<75;j++)
        {
        int rgb = levels.getRGB(i,j);
        int sx = getMappedCoordX(levels.getRGB(i,j));
        int sy = getMappedCoordY(levels.getRGB(i,j));
        try{
            if(materialRGBmap[(i*32)+j]==solRGB)
                {
                int[] coords = physicsRules.getSolidMovableStatic(getFree(i,j+1),getFree(i-1,j),getFree(i+1,j),getFree(i-1,j+1),getFree(i+1,j+1),i*8,j*8);
                levels.setRGB(i,j,map_null.getRGB(0,0));
                levels.setRGB(coords[0]/8,coords[1]/8,rgb);
                }
            if(materialRGBmap[(i*32)+j]==liqRGB)
                {
                int[] coords = physicsRules.getLiquidMovableStatic(getFree(i,j+1),getFree(i-1,j),getFree(i+1,j),i*8,j*8);
                levels.setRGB(i,j,map_null.getRGB(0,0));
                levels.setRGB(coords[0]/8,coords[1]/8,rgb);
                }
            if(materialRGBmap[(i*32)+j]==gasRGB)
                {
                int[] coords = physicsRules.getGasMovableStatic(getFree(i,j+1),getFree(i-1,j),getFree(i+1,j),getFree(i+1,j),i*8,j*8);
                levels.setRGB(i,j,map_null.getRGB(0,0));
                levels.setRGB(coords[0]/8,coords[1]/8,rgb);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("lolcat error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code in `PhysicsRules`. (shown as variable `physicsRules` above)

```
public int[] getLiquidMovable(boolean onGround, boolean leftFree, boolean rightFree, int x, int y)
{
return onGround?(rand.nextInt(2)==0 && leftFree?new int[]{x-8, y}:(rightFree?new int[]{x+8,y}:new int[]{x,y})):new int[]{x,y+8};
}

public static int[] getLiquidMovableStatic(boolean onGround, boolean leftFree, boolean rightFree, int x, int y)
{
return onGround?(Srand.nextInt(2)==0 && leftFree?new int[]{x-8, y}:(rightFree?new int[]{x+8,y}:new int[]{x,y})):new int[]{x,y+8};
}

public int[] getSolidMovable(boolean onGround, boolean leftFree, boolean rightFree, boolean leftUFree, boolean rightUFree, int x, int y)
{
return onGround?(rand.nextInt(2)==0 && leftFree && leftUFree?new int[]{x-8, y}:(rightFree && rightUFree?new int[]{x+8,y}:new int[]{x,y})):new int[]{x,y+8};
}

public int[] getSolidMovableStatic(boolean onGround, boolean leftFree, boolean rightFree, boolean leftUFree, boolean rightUFree, int x, int y)
{
return onGround?(Srand.nextInt(2)==0 && leftFree && leftUFree?new int[]{x-8, y}:(rightFree && rightUFree?new int[]{x+8,y}:new int[]{x,y})):new int[]{x,y+8};
}

public int[] getGasMovable(boolean leftFree, boolean rightFree, boolean upFree, boolean downFree, int x, int y)
{
int dir = rand.nextInt(4);
return dir==0 && upFree?new int[]{x,y-8}:(dir==1 && leftFree?new int[]{x+8,y}:(dir==2 && downFree?new int[]{x,y+8}:(dir==3 && rightFree?new int[]{x-8,y}:new int[]{x,y})));
}

public static int[] getGasMovableStatic(boolean leftFree, boolean rightFree, boolean upFree, boolean downFree, int x, int y)
{
int dir = Srand.nextInt(4);
return dir==0 && upFree?new int[]{x,y-8}:(dir==1 && leftFree?new int[]{x+8,y}:(dir==2 && downFree?new int[]{x,y+8}:(dir==3 && rightFree?new int[]{x-8,y}:new int[]{x,y})));
}
```

Comment: Please indent the code in your question. It's incredibly hard to read at the moment. (I'd encourage you to embrace whitespace in general, to be honest...)

Comment: You title refers to a "physics" code, but your text makes it clear that the problem has nothing at all to do with simulated physics and everything to do with either file access or initializing your in-memory representation.

Comment: The code is for handling physics via initially loading a file, then editing it.

Comment: @BottleFact: but your coding problem has nothing to do with physics or simulation, so this part of your title is irrelevant and unnecessary. Just a suggestion for helping you since a cleaner question usually gets better and quicker answers. Also, you will want to get rid of your magic numbers in your code. Also consider using just a little math to prevent this problem from happening.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What math/magic numbers? Are the 'magic numbers' the dimensions of the level?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 0):

J is from 0 to 75 but i is used with 32-wide steps(multiplied by 32) so J overlaps to next elements variable field.

```
materialRGBmap[(i*32)+j]
```

is using map elements used by the last iteration. If you change limit of j to 32, you can compute/use only the 32-wide field per iteration of i.

Plus, you are not doing element-wise computation as parallel. You are changing elements one by one, not all at the same time. You need temporary array to store results, finall y copying all to original array.

Deep note: stay away from putting single dots(painting part) when you use 1000 x 1000 area. Editing an image then drawing that is faster.

Comment: It is meant to do that, to turn the two X and Y coordinates into a number for the array.

Comment: What is your falling sand area in terms of pixels/elements?

Comment: I used printStackTrace for the error, aparrently it is an ArrayOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds! Could it be I'm not clamping the coord[] arrays?

Comment: Just redimention the area to 32*100 or just use materialRGBmap[(i*75)+j]

Comment: Am using (i*75)+j, not working still. D= Updating the Question with the code in PhysicsRules, if it helps.

Comment: Which array is being reported for exception ?

Comment: An array in setRGB, but the error is now gone. Physics not working still though.

Comment: Was the error was because of me? I will delete t5his answer if yes.

Comment: No, it was that I forgot to clamp some numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by physics not working? Particles not falling? Particles fall onto an invisible barrier? Particles warp to ground?

Comment: Your physicsRules have only leftfree and rightfree. There are not any downfree, i dont see any downfree for solids or fluids. Only gas. Are you using solids? This could be issue.

Comment: for solids and liquids, the downFree is renames as onGround. It is calculated in the same way. And Yes, i am using solids

Comment: So it randomly chooses one if all free ? When you have only downside is free it just get unlucky to get a downward random number i think.

Comment: If it can fall, it falls, otherwise it picks left or right at random. If it is not able to, it tries the other way, and if that is blocked, then it stays still. Maybe I'm calculating it wrong in PhysicsRules? Rewriting PhysicsRules.

Comment: Are you doing update on the actual xy-array or a temporary array? If it is done in actual array then each iteration can purge the last iteration since inner loop is J. Can you put updated values to a temporary array then in the end copy whole temp to original array? This way it is parallel. Or this is just serial computation that every elements is dependant to all other elements.

Comment: Im doing it on the actual array

Comment: Maaybe using a local-temporary array to put results then copying it back when done, could save elements from each other attacking.

Comment: That was worked on a fluid solver once. Without it, there was weird physics such as warping or not moving at all.

Comment: Got a NullPointerException. From your temporary array method

Comment: Because of rewritten physics or temporary array?

Comment: Did you init it like materialRGBmap[]=new .... then using a loop to initialize each element to zero?

Comment: If init is no problem, how are you copying the array to original? Element by element should work with no problem. Using equation operator may make the original array deleted by garbage collector.